# twisted python - can't import connectProtocol

Tags: python, twisted

I am facing problem in making my client program. While importing connectProtocol it fails.

from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint, connectProtocol

the error I am getting is

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clnt.py", line 3, in 
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint, connectProtocol
***ImportError: cannot import name connectProtocol****

This is a simple client. Server side things are in good shape.
Python version is Python 2.7.5+

My Ubuntu machine is 13.10 and
twisted package installed is 13.0.0

[edit]

I tried with ipython and found that connectProtocol is not available in endpoints. The following are the classes available in endpoints class in my machine

In [3]: from twisted.internet.endpoints.

twisted.internet.endpoints.AdoptedStreamServerEndpoint  twisted.internet.endpoints.TCP6ClientEndpoint
twisted.internet.endpoints.SSL4ClientEndpoint           twisted.internet.endpoints.TCP6ServerEndpoint
twisted.internet.endpoints.SSL4ServerEndpoint           twisted.internet.endpoints.UNIXClientEndpoint
twisted.internet.endpoints.StandardIOEndpoint           twisted.internet.endpoints.UNIXServerEndpoint
twisted.internet.endpoints.TCP4ClientEndpoint           twisted.internet.endpoints.clientFromString
twisted.internet.endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint           twisted.internet.endpoints.serverFromString

[/edit]

Thanks
~S

Comment: Looking at the documentation one sees that in version 13.0.0 it is not there: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.0.0/api/twisted.internet.endpoints.html, while in version 13.1.0 it is: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/api/twisted.internet.endpoints.html

Comment: Thanks for the comments. How do I get the 13.1.0 in my system, as I have done just apt-get install twisted, and this is what I got - which means the version compatible for my system is 13.0.0. Is there any way I can bump up the version manually?

Comment: Use virtualenv and install twisted in a new virtual environment by using `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sreenatha said, `twisted.internet.endpoints.connectProtocol` was introduced in twisted version 13.1.

I would recommend that you install a more recent version of Twisted into a virtual environment:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv python-dev
$ virtualenv lets-twisted
$ ./lets-twisted/bin/pip install twisted
$ ./lets-twisted/bin/twistd --help
```

Answer (score -1):

twisted.internet.endpoints.**connectProtocol** was [introduced](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/api/twisted.internet.endpoints.connectProtocol.html)  in **twisted version 13.1**.

Since you're using Ubuntu 13.10, try the following to update your twisted.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install python-pip`

`sudo pip install twisted --upgrade`

If you're still facing weird issues, I suggest you try removing twisted using below command and reinstall(above 3 commands).

 `sudo apt-get remove python-twisted`

Comment: Do not ever `sudo pip install twisted`, especially if you already have Twisted installed from a system package manager.  This is dangerous advice that can break your operating system.